# How to I set "rounded corners" inside a style in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[karl/.style ={help lines,color=blue!50}]
\filldraw[step=.5cm,karl] (-1.4,-1.4) grid (1.4,1.4);

[scheme/.style ={draw, rounded corners}]
\draw[scheme] (-0.9,-1) rectangle (1,0.9);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The first part works, the style "karl" gets correctly defined and the grid is blue-ish.

The second part doesn't work, latex complains:

```
ERROR: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/scheme' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

[image: first wrong result]

The "rounded corners" by themselves do work though:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[karl/.style ={help lines,color=blue!50}]
\filldraw[step=.5cm,karl] (-1.4,-1.4) grid (1.4,1.4);
\draw[rounded corners] (-0.9,-1) rectangle (1,0.9);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Second image, no style]

How do I make a style that would include rounded corners?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The style definition is an option of `tikzpicture` environment, you should not put two optional parameters [...] [...] in your environment but only one with styles separated by commas.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[karl/.style ={help lines,color=blue!50},
    scheme/.style ={draw, rounded corners}]
  \filldraw[step=.5cm,karl] (-1.4,-1.4) grid (1.4,1.4);
  \draw[scheme] (-0.9,-1) rectangle (1,0.9);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If your styles are valid for all your `tikzpicture` environments, you can use `\tikzset`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    karl/.style ={help lines,color=blue!50},
    scheme/.style ={draw, rounded corners}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \filldraw[step=.5cm,karl] (-1.4,-1.4) grid (1.4,1.4);
  \draw[scheme] (-0.9,-1) rectangle (1,0.9);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```